# CatalogVersion with catalogId 'xxxProductCatalog' and version 'Staged' not found

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

i follow that tutorial

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094418&showComments=true

first i changed impex names to mystore name.

Then i went to hac console and updated only my extension, mystoreinitialdata.

But it gives those errors:

```
Creating project data for mystoreinitialdata ...
Begin importing common data for [mystoremystoreinitialdata]
Begin importing product catalog data for [xxx]
Begin importing content catalog data for [xx]
Begin synchronizing Product Catalog [xxx]




Error creating sample data for mystoreainitialdata. See console output.
```

> ERROR [hybrisHTTP39] [Initialization]
>   de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.UnknownIdentifierException:
>   CatalogVersion with catalogId 'xxxProductCatalog' and version 'Staged'
>   not found!

i searched and there is no xxxProductCatalog in my code.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the ImportData created in your InitialDataSystemSetup has valid names for ProductCatalog and Content Catalog attributes. Like this:

```
final List<ImportData> importData = new ArrayList<ImportData>();

final ImportData sampleImportData = new ImportData();
sampleImportData.setProductCatalogName("mystore");
sampleImportData.setContentCatalogNames(Arrays.asList("mystore"));
sampleImportData.setStoreNames(Arrays.asList("mystore"));
importData.add(sampleImportData);

getCoreDataImportService().execute(this, context, importData);
getEventService().publishEvent(new CoreDataImportedEvent(context, importData));

getSampleDataImportService().execute(this, context, importData);
getEventService().publishEvent(new SampleDataImportedEvent(context, importData));
```

Also make sure, that catalogs with the names "mystoreContentCatalog" and "mystoreProductCatalog" are created in the impex files in the following files:

/mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/contentCatalogs/mystoreContentCatalog/catalog.impex

```
$contentCatalog=mystoreContentCatalog
$languages=ja,en,de,zh

INSERT_UPDATE ContentCatalog;id[unique=true]
;$contentCatalog

INSERT_UPDATE CatalogVersion;catalog(id)[unique=true];version[unique=true];active;languages(isoCode)
;$contentCatalog;Staged;false;$languages
;$contentCatalog;Online;true;$languages
```

/mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/productCatalogs/mystoreProductCatalog/catalog.impex

```
$productCatalog=mystoreProductCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]
$languages=ja,en,de,zh

INSERT_UPDATE Catalog;id[unique=true]
;$productCatalog

INSERT_UPDATE CatalogVersion;catalog(id)[unique=true];version[unique=true];active;languages(isoCode);readPrincipals(uid)
;$productCatalog;Staged;false;$languages;employeegroup
;$productCatalog;Online;true;$languages;employeegroup
```

Comment: If this does not help, please share your console log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430469/catalog-names-are-not-created-hybris