# Catalog names are not created (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to create a new catalog.

I followed that steps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414933/9708984

```
//resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/mystoreContentCatalog/cms-content.impex
```

here despite I made

`$contentCatalogName=mystoreContent Catalog'`, on `backoffice/catalog`s,

I only see mystore catalog with id, name is empty.

for `powertools` it has name, `Powertools Content Catalog`.

I did `ant initialize`' , it created 3 catalogs `mystorecontent catalog, mystoreclassfication,mystoreprductcatalog` but they dont have name.

`$contentCatalog=electronicsContentCatalog $contentCatalogName=Electronics Content Catalog`

this contentcatalogname is not used anywhere for any of the stores; `mystore electronic,powertools or apparel` .

but other 3 has name. why `mystore` does not have? what is that contentcatalogname for? the path is

`electronicsstore/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/electronicsContentCatalog/cms-responsive-content.impex for electronics`

Answer (score 1):

The name is a localized attribute. For localized attributes, the accelerator has its own files. Check the files named catalog_XX.impex in the directory

```
resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/sampledata/contentCatalogs/mystoreContentCatalog/
```

The XX represents the isocode of the language. So en means English, de German etc. In the file, set the name like this:

```
$lang=en
$contentCatalog=mystoreContentCatalog

UPDATE ContentCatalog;id[unique=true];name[lang=$lang]
;$contentCatalog;"mystore Content Catalog"
```

Comment: i looked that directory. `cms-content_en.impex` for example, does not have name attribute. it has only `$contentCatalog`. or other languages. cms-content.impex` does  have `$$contentCatalogName`. also `$productCatalogName` has name but it was not created on both languages and `products_en.impex`